# Why is VBA array not loading integers

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

Here is a function I found online to help loop through values and select pivot filter items that match the values. My problem is that the array created in the Sub Filter_Bana does not get loaded with the values from the range named as "Bana" (aka varItemList). The range "Bana" consists of about twenty numbers (integers). When I run the sub (at the bottom), I keep receiving the MsgBox "None of filter list items found" from the function. I have been trying to figure this out for a while and don't think any of the named integer list "Bana" is getting loaded into "varItemList." In other words, when varItemList is passed to the function, the array is empty. Please see code:

**EDIT: I found the problem. The problems I was having related to two issues: 1) I am bad at VBA, 2) the data type of the pivot items in my pivot field did not match the data type of the array. I switched the array components to a 5-character text and adjusted the SQL query to bring in my investorNumber as a 5-character text (i.e. the array needed to be loaded with a character string and my pivot field needed data of the character type; if there was a way to do this with integers, I'd love to know. **

```
Private Function Filter_PivotField(pvtField As PivotField, _
    varItemList As Variant)
    Dim strItem1 As Long, blTmp As Boolean, i As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    Debug.Print varItemList
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With pvtField
        If .Orientation = xlPageField Then .EnableMultiplePageItems = True
        For i = LBound(varItemList) To UBound(varItemList)
            blTmp = Not (IsError(.PivotItems(varItemList(i)).Visible))
            If blTmp Then
                strItem1 = .PivotItems(varItemList(i))
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        If strItem1 = "" Then
            MsgBox "None of filter list items found."
            Exit Function
        End If
        .PivotItems(strItem1).Visible = True
        For i = 1 To .PivotItems.Count
            If .PivotItems(i) <> strItem1 And _
                .PivotItems(i).Visible = True Then
                .PivotItems(i).Visible = False
            End If
        Next i
        For i = LBound(varItemList) To UBound(varItemList)
            .PivotItems(varItemList(i)).Visible = True
        Next i
    End With
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function


Sub Filter_Bana()
    Filter_PivotField _
        pvtField:=Sheets("Pres1&2_Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("investorNumber"), _
        varItemList:=Application.Transpose(Sheets("Controls").Range("Bana"))

End Sub`
```

Comment: First stop with anything like this - get rid of the `On Error Resume Next` statement and actually [debug your code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

Comment: `Debug.Print varItemList` you cannot debug.print an array like this

Comment: Sorry Macro Man. That's a good point.

Comment: yes, I've gotten rid of the debug.print thing. that was a remnant from when i was trying to figure out if there's anything in the array.

after removing the 'on Error Resume Next,' the error I'm getting is "Unable to get the pivotItems property of the PivotField class. Any thoughts?

Comment: You declare `strItem1` As Long and in the if/then condition you check it against an empty string value `""`. Are you receiving a mismatch error?

Comment: @Parfait - That's also an error on my part. I switch it back to string (as consistent with the code I got which does work). Now I'm getting an "Unable to get PivotItems property of the PivotField class" error when attempt this line:

blTmp = Not (IsError(.PivotItems(varItemList(i)).Visible))

Comment: `Debug.Print Join(varItemList, ", ")` is a useful quick way of seeing the contents of that array in the immediate window.

Comment: You can't use IsError() like this: `IsError(.PivotItems(varItemList(i)).Visible)` - `IsError()` is not designed to trap and report run-time errors such as you'd get when trying to access a non-existent member of the PivotItems list (assuming that's what's going on).

Answer (score 0):

This code works. The only other key is making sure my array is loaded with character type data (not integers) and that the pivot field also contains character type data (adjusted in the query/not displayed)

```
Private Function Filter_PivotField(pvtField As PivotField, _
    varItemList As Variant)
    Dim strItem1 As String, blTmp As Boolean, i As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With pvtField
        If .Orientation = xlPageField Then .EnableMultiplePageItems = True
        For i = LBound(varItemList) To UBound(varItemList)
            blTmp = Not (IsError(.PivotItems(varItemList(i)).Visible))
            If blTmp Then
                strItem1 = .PivotItems(varItemList(i))
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        If strItem1 = "" Then
            MsgBox "None of filter list items found."
            Exit Function
        End If
        .PivotItems(strItem1).Visible = True
        For i = 1 To .PivotItems.Count
            If .PivotItems(i) <> strItem1 And _
                .PivotItems(i).Visible = True Then
                .PivotItems(i).Visible = False
            End If
        Next i
        For i = LBound(varItemList) To UBound(varItemList)
            .PivotItems(varItemList(i)).Visible = True
        Next i
    End With
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function


Sub Filter_Bana()
Filter_PivotField _
    pvtField:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pres1_2_Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("investorNumber"), _
    varItemList:=Application.Transpose(Sheets("Controls").Range("Bana"))

End Sub
```